# qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError Parameters

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm working on an AOM to execute UFT Scripts.

I'm just wondering if what are the other parameter values applicable on qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError script aside from "NexStep"

I want to pause the run and display the error message instead of proceeding to next step.

Here's the script portion I want to modify

qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError = "NextStep"

Answer (score 0):

According to [OnError Property documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/AutomationObjectModel/Content/QuickTest%7ERunSettings%7EOnError.html), your options are:

- `NextStep` (Default): UFT proceeds to the next step in the test or component when an error occurs.
- `Dialog`: UFT displays an error message dialog box when an error occurs. You must click a button on the message box to continue or end the run session. This option has no effect when running a test using automation, since when UFT One is opened via automation, it runs in silent mode, meaning that even if it is visible, message boxes are not opened.
- `NextIteration`: UFT proceeds to the next iteration of the action when an error occurs.  (This value is not relevant for business components.)
- `NextTestIteration`: UFT proceeds to the next iteration of the test when an error occurs. (This value is not relevant for business components.)
  Stop--UFT stops the test or component run when an error occurs.

`Dialog` seems to be what you are looking for:

```
qtApp.Test.Settings.Run.OnError = "Dialog"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although "Dialog" seems not working since as per description, it has no effect when running via Automation

Comment: @mrjyyyy sorry to be the bearer of bad news but these are the qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError parameters you were asking for.

Comment: I tend to agree: It used to work as documented, but seems to be buggy meanwhile ;(